# Transforming and Appending DataFrames in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame called "df_1".

```
        Date    HomeTeam    AwayTeam
0   8/14/1993   Arsenal     Coventry
1   8/14/1993   Aston Villa    QPR
2   8/14/1993   Chelsea     Blackburn
```

I also have DataFrame named "df_2".

```
     Team    Game N.      Value
 0  Arsenal      0         -1
 1   QPR         1          2
 2  Blackburn    2          4
 3  Coventry     0          3
 4  Chelsea      2          0
 5  Aston Villa  1         -2
```

The numbers in column "Game N." in df_2 correspond to the numbers of the index in df_1. Also the team names are the same in both tables.

Is it possible to assign (append) each value from column "Value" from df_2 to the corresponding row (index) in df_1 by creating two new columns with names, say Value_Home and Value_Away. This is what output I am trying to achieve:

```
      Date     HomeTeam     AwayTeam    Value_Home  Value_Away
 0  8/14/1993   Arsenal     Coventry        -1           3
 1  8/14/1993   Aston Villa    QPR          -2           2
 2  8/14/1993   Chelsea     Blackburn        0           4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Merge `df_1` with `df_2`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) twice<sup>1</sup>:

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['8/14/1993', '8/14/1993', '8/14/1993'],
                    'HomeTeam': ['Arsenal', 'Aston Villa', 'Chelsea'],
                    'AwayTeam': ['Coventry', 'QPR', 'Blackburn']})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Team': ['Arsenal', 'QPR', 'Blackburn', 'Coventry', 'Chelsea', 'Aston Villa'],
                    'Game N.': [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1],
                    'Value': [-1, 2, 4, 3, 0, -2]})
df_1 = df_1.reset_index()

result = (df_1.merge(df_2.rename(columns={'Team':'HomeTeam', 'Game N.':'index','Value':'Value_Home'}))
             .merge(df_2.rename(columns={'Team':'AwayTeam', 'Game N.':'index','Value':'Value_Away'})))
result = result.drop('index', axis=1)
print(result)
```

yields

```
        Date     HomeTeam   AwayTeam  Value_Home  Value_Away
0  8/14/1993      Arsenal   Coventry          -1           3
1  8/14/1993  Aston Villa        QPR          -2           2
2  8/14/1993      Chelsea  Blackburn           0           4
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
By default, `merge` merges on all column names that the two DataFrames share in common. So the trick is to rename the columns of `df_2` so the merge occurs on the appropriate columns.
For example, given `df_1` and `df_2` like this:

```
In [39]: df_1
Out[39]: 
   index       Date     HomeTeam   AwayTeam
0      0  8/14/1993      Arsenal   Coventry
1      1  8/14/1993  Aston Villa        QPR
2      2  8/14/1993      Chelsea  Blackburn

In [40]: df_2
Out[40]: 
          Team  Game N.  Value
0      Arsenal        0     -1
1          QPR        1      2
2    Blackburn        2      4
3     Coventry        0      3
4      Chelsea        2      0
5  Aston Villa        1     -2
```

we wish to merge `df_1`'s `index` and `HomeTeam` columns with `df_2`'s `Game N.` and `Team` columns.
So if we rename the columns of `df_2` like this:

```
In [31]: df_2.rename(columns={'Team':'HomeTeam', 'Game N.':'index','Value':'Value_Home'})
Out[36]: 
      HomeTeam  index  Value_Home
0      Arsenal      0          -1
1          QPR      1           2
2    Blackburn      2           4
3     Coventry      0           3
4      Chelsea      2           0
5  Aston Villa      1          -2
```

then merging the two DataFrames produces

```
In [38]: df_1.merge(df_2.rename(columns={'Team':'HomeTeam', 'Game N.':'index','Value':'Value_Home'}))
Out[38]: 
   index       Date     HomeTeam   AwayTeam  Value_Home
0      0  8/14/1993      Arsenal   Coventry          -1
1      1  8/14/1993  Aston Villa        QPR          -2
2      2  8/14/1993      Chelsea  Blackburn           0
```

The `Value_Away` column can be obtained in the same way.